# How to get g++ to warn on unused member variables

Tags: c++, g++

g++ generates warnings for unused local variables. Is it possible to have g++ warn for unused class member variables and/or global variables?

```
class Obj {
 public:
  Obj(int a, int b) : num1(a), num2(b) {}
  int addA(int i) {
    return i + num1;
  }

 private:
  int num1;
  int num2;
};
```

How do I get g++ to warn me that `num2` is unused?

UPDATE:
I am currently compiling with:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic *.cc -o myprogram
```

Comment: It's at least used in the member initialization list?!?

Comment: You could try `-Wall`.

Comment: There's no such warning, because that would need much more analysis.

Comment: I seem to recall I've seen that warning before. But I don't recall if it was GCC, ICC, Clang or MSVC.

Comment: in Clang this is -Wunused-private-fields as shown here: https://web.archive.org/web/20170403211203/https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not aware of any such warning. Additionally I'll speculate that the reason it doesn't exist is because it can't be reliably generated in all cases, so they elected to not spend effort making it work for some subset of cases. For example, if the class `friend`s another function that's in a library, the compiler would have no way of knowing if that library mutated any particular class attribute or not.

Comment: Thanks @mark, that makes a lot of sense. The usage of libraries seem to thwart many of my idealistic programming conventions.

Answer (score 11):

Clang's `-Wunused-private-field` enables the warning you're asking for. On your code base, it shows:

```
$ clang -Wunused-private-field /tmp/nic.cpp  
/tmp/nic.cpp:10:22: warning: private field 'num2' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
             int num2;
                 ^
1 warning generated.
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net) ([download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppcheck/)). `cppcheck --enable=style` does exactly what you need, among other useful things.

Comment: I see you use Ubuntu, cppcheck is available in the repository.

Comment: Thanks @user3556781, I've cloned the git repo and am checking it out now. How do you see that I use Ubuntu? Thanks for the pointer about the package repo.