# How to find unused properties for iOS class?

Tags: ios, xcode

I cannot find any similar questions on this topic, which seems strange..

I have what is turning out to be a rather large project. As I build each chunk, I'm aware that I must be making properties and other resources, that do not end up being used.

Is there a way to find these?

Comment: I think something close/similar is [How to get g++ to warn on unused member variables](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23436619). But C++ classes don't have properties like iOS classes.

Comment: AppCode is good at showing these kinds of things. I know for a fact that unused #imports and methods show up in grey.

Comment: @RhythmicFistman -- great name -- what is AppCode? Is it an alternative IDE?

Comment: It is a matter of class semantic, a property is an inherent part of a class, whether it's used or not.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks. Is there anything in Instruments.app?

Comment: @BùiThanhHải If you never use the property in the class that defines it, then it is probably of little value to clients of your class, and it probably is a remnant of something you don't need anymore.  Exceptions are possible, but being able to clean things up as they become unnecessary is better than keeping it around to do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I always need this too in my projects. What I do is either use search for `.property` or `setProperty` etc. in the whole project.

Or I traverse the .h files and comment out the property declarations that I suspect I might not be using and hit `Command+b` and see if it gives any errors.

I hope there is a function/tool specifically built for this need.